# Should I ask for confirmation of my admission from University academic department

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I have applied to two Canadian universities for MS program. One of them has accepted my application and has given me admission. While for the other one, status is "Under department review". I am waiting for second university response. But the problem is that I have to give my confirmation with in two weeks time. In this case, can I ask them to accelerate the decision process for me and can give me a definite answer? Is this polite to do it? Do I need to mention the University name in mail?

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41852/inquiring-about-phd-status-and-mentioning-standing-offers?rq=1

Comment: Interestingly, "fasten" doesn't mean "to make faster," it means to hold in one spot: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fasten

Comment: You should absolutely contact them with the information about the info about your other acceptance and what your deadline is.  They may or may not make a decision before your deadline, but they will appreciate knowing about the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in this case it is appropriate to contact the department/program head or admissions administrator and inform them that you have another acceptance. Rather than ask for them to "hurry up," it would be more polite to say, "I have received another offer of acceptance that requires my response within two weeks. Will your department be able to make its admission decisions within that time line?"

Comment: Do I need to mention the university name in my mail?

Comment: I don't think that is necessary. I suppose the department could ask for proof that you received an acceptance somewhere else to make sure that there is a real need to work faster than their normal timeline (rather than a student who just wants them to work faster and therefore fabricates a non-existent offer somewhere else). However, I never heard of this for school admissions. I would leave it out unless they ask.

Comment: If the university you are waiting to hear from is your top choice, you could mention, "Your program is my top choice and I would prefer to attend your program if I am accepted."